# Current directory in CLion

Tags: c, clion

I use Clion 2016.1. For example, I run such code in the directory `~/CLionProjects/Tutorial`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char * string;
    string = "Hello, everyone";
    printf(string);
}
```

Why does Clion go for this code to this directory?:

```
/home/ken/.CLion2016.1/system/cmake/generated/Tutorial-9a39f70/9a39f70/Debug/Tutorial
Hello, everyone
Process finished with exit code 15
```

How to make the programs running in "normal" directory `~/CLionProjects/Tutorial`?

**UPD**

I want to read a "data.csv" file locates in the current directory (where main.c is). But CLion looks for it in `/home/ken/.CLion2016.1/system/cmake/generated/Tutorial-9a39f70/9a39f70/Debug/Tutorial`. How to make that CLion looks for `data.csv` in `~/CLionProjects/Tutorial`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to appear your binaries in a folder you've specified, you need to tell it CLion by adjusting your CMakeLists.txt like this:

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
```

Edit:

Somehow it seems that these options are not respected in the current version of CLion (2016.2). Therefore one might has to change the desired output directory via: Build, Execution, Deployment | CMake settings and set it there.

Comment: what about directory where I want to get text files from?

Comment: I don't quite understand. You can navigate relatively from your source directory, if you've specified your output binary as described above.

Answer (score 1):

This is more an answer for the UPD question than the original. But the answers are related. .EXE is built into a folder that depends on the build options (debug, release, etc). An exe's default working directory is the folder where the exe is found. That is the folder where the program will look for data files, etc, unless you tell it to look elsewhere.

You can change the working directory for the exe with a runtime option. I made a YouTube tutorial for my COSC1030 (Beginning C++) students but the solution is the same for everyone: https://youtu.be/dTtZEAfh_LM

Answer (score 0):

> For CLion v2016.1 and earlier

To change build output path, open CLion `Settings` and go to `Build, Execution, Deployment` | `CMake` settings and set it there.